# Converting enum type to *enum type in go

Tags: go, enums

go newbie here,
I want to convert an enum from `Day` type to `*Mappings` type, since they are strings, I am unable to assign pointer values to the enum directly.
I tried to assign the value to a temporary variable

```
var id = MON
*r = id
```

but that didn't work, I want it to be assigned to a pointer so that I can have nil values for the type. I can't change the `Day` struct or `Mappings` struct type.
How can I assign the value to the receiver `*r` without running into the pointer issue?
playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/5SNx0I-Prc2

```
package main

type Day string

const (
    SUNDAY  Day = ""
    MONDAY  Day = "MONDAY"
    TUESDAY Day = "TUESDAY"
)

type Mappings string

const (
    SUN Mappings = ""
    MON Mappings = "MON"
    TUE Mappings = "TUE"
)

func main() {

    type A struct {
        day Day
    }

    type B struct {
        day *Mappings
    }

    sourceObj := A{day: MONDAY}

    destObj := B{}

    destObj.day.To(sourceObj.day)

}

func (r *Mappings) To(m Day) {
    switch m {
    case MONDAY:
        *r = MON
    case TUESDAY:
        *r = TUE
    }
}
```

Comment: It fails because `r` is `nil` and therefore `*r` is a runtime error. i.e. It is illegal to de-reference a `nil` pointer. You have to first initialize `B.day` to a non-nil value before you use the `To` method: https://play.golang.org/p/X7VTXy81dY8. Or you could simply not use a pointer field: https://play.golang.org/p/UphPneQCvNZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`destObj.day` will be `nil`. Hence, `*r` and `*destObj.day` will be a run time exception.
Allocate space for `destObj.day` by using the `new` keyword.
Example:

```
destObj := B{new(Mappings)}
```